# How to effectively override a procedure-local variable in TCL

Tags: tcl

So I have the following situation:

```
$ ls -l
-r--r----- 1.tcl
-rw-rw---- 2.tcl

$ cat 1.tcl
proc foo {args} {
  puts "$bar"
}
```

and I need to make `1.tcl` print something other than `"can't read \"bar\""`. In a good programming language, the obvious solution would be

```
$ cat > 2.tcl
set -global bar "hello, world"
foo
```

What would be a reasonable workaround in TCL? Unfortunately the real `foo` is a long function that I can't really make a copy of or `sed` to a temporary file at runtime.

Comment: One can set a global variable with the same name and link to it e.g. by adding a `global` invocation at the beginning of the procedure body, like Glenn suggested. But it's not going to work. Somewhere in the procedure code, before the value of `bar` is printed, the value will be set to the value that is used now. Linking to a global variable can't prevent that change from happening.

Comment: I would have probably said the same thing if I saw this question, but the function is actually broken and I'm not allowed to fix it. Clearly the code has been copy pasted from somewhere else or something, but the variable is definitely undefined. (Or have I misunderstood what you meant?)

Comment: No, the misunderstanding was mine. I simply assumed that no one would work with a procedure that had undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this *for your specific example*

```
$ cat 2.tcl
source 1.tcl
set bar "Hello, bar!"
# add a "global bar" command to the foo procedure
proc foo [info args foo] "global bar; [info body foo]"
foo

$ tclsh 2.tcl
Hello, bar!
```

Clearly this doesn't scale very well.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable is simply undefined, the easiest way would be to patch the procedure with a definition:

```
proc foo [info args foo] "set bar \"hello, world\" ; [info body foo]"
```

You can also accomplish this using a read trace and a helper command. This removes the problem I mentioned above, where local assignments destroy the value you wanted to inject.

The original procedure, with an added command that sets the local variable to a value which is later printed.

```
proc foo args {
    set bar foobar
    puts "$bar"
}
% foo
foobar
```

Create a global variable (it doesn't matter if the name is the same or not).

```
set bar "hello, world"
```

Create a helper command that gets the name of the local variable, links to it, and assigns the value of the global variable to it. Since we already know the name we could hardcode it in the procedure, but this is more flexible.

```
proc readbar {name args} {
    upvar 1 $name var
    global bar
    set var $bar
}
```

Add the trace to the body of the `foo` procedure. The trace will fire whenever the local variable `bar` is read, i.e. something attempts to retrieve its value. When the trace fires, the command `readbar` is called: it overwrites the current value of the variable with the globally set value.

```
proc foo [info args foo] "trace add variable bar read readbar; [info body foo]"

% foo
hello, world
```

If one doesn't want to pollute the namespace with the helper command, one can use an anonymous function instead:

```
proc foo [info args foo] [format {trace add variable bar read {apply {{name args} {
    upvar 1 $name var
    global bar
    set var $bar
}}} ; %s} [info body foo]]
```

Documentation:
[apply](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/apply.htm),
[format](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm),
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[info](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[trace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/trace.htm),
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: Notice that in his question "bar" is not set at all.  He does not want to change 1.tcl.  Also see his comment in reply to my first edit.   I'm not sure that the OP's question reflects what the OP really wants.

Comment: @BradLanam You're right I didn't really mean override, "define from outside the function" would have been a better way of putting it. Anyway this answer covers both cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
source 1.tcl

try {
  foo
} on error {err res} {
  set einfo [dict get $res -errorinfo]
  if { [regexp {no such variable} $einfo] } {
    puts "hello, world"
    return -code 0
  } else {
    puts $einfo
    return -code [dict get $res -code]
  }
}
```

Comment: This clearly isn't applicable to the general case of controlling the value of an undefined variable inside a procedure.

Comment: The above comment was in response to a previous edit.  See the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's procedures do not resolve variables to anything other than local variables by default. You have to explicitly ask for them to refer to something else (e.g., with `global`, `variable` or `upvar`). This means that it's always possible to see at a glance whether non-local things are happening, and that the script won't work.

It's possible to override this behaviour with a variable resolver, but Tcl doesn't really expose that API in its script interface. Some extensions do more. For example, it *might* work to use [incr Tcl] (i.e., itcl) as that does that sort of thing for variables in its objects. I can't remember if Expect also does this, or if that uses special-cased code for handling its variables.

Of course, you could get really sneaky and override the behaviour of `proc`.

```
rename proc real_proc
real_proc proc {name arguments body} {
    uplevel 1 [list real_proc $name $arguments "global bar;$body"]
}
```

That's rather nasty though.